# Find the set of limit points of the following sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am particularly interested on the sequences $a_n = n \alpha - [n \alpha]$ and $b_n = \sin (\pi n \alpha)$ where $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$. We wish to find the set of limit points of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$

#### Try:

> def of limit point in my book: $x$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ if
> $\exists$ a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}
>  x_{n_k} = x$.

which I believe can be translated as follows:

$x$ is limit point of $(x_n)$ if $\exists$ index $k>0$ so that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N>0$ so that $n_k > N \implies |x_{n_k} - x | <\epsilon $

Evidently for sequence $(a_n)$ we may see that any multiple of $\alpha$ is a limit point.

the image of $(a_n)$ is the interval $[0,1)$. Is the set of all limit points this interval?

Comment: Assuming that your $[x]$ is my $\lfloor x\rfloor$, the integer part of $x$, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189397/why-is-this-quotient-space-not-hausdorff/189402#189402) should take care of the first sequence. Note that it’s not possible for all multiples of $\alpha$ to be limit points, because $0\le a_n<1$ for every $n$. I’ve not thought about the second sequence, but I suspect that something very similar happens.

Comment: In the translation should be noted that $\{n_k\}$ is a sequence of distinct natural numbers.

Comment: I would like to clarify is [ . ] the floor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $a_n\in [0,1]$ and  $b_n\in [-1,1]$ for each natural $n$. On the other hand, the 
set $\{a_n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and the set $B=\{b_n\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ 
(so the sets of the limit points of $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are $[0,1]$ and $[-1,1]$, respectively). 
Both these facts are well-known. For the first, see, for instance, my detailed recent answer 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661094/proving-the-density-of-a-function-in-an-interval).
To prove the second, note that for each $n$, $b_n=\sin 2\pi a'_n$, where 
$a'_n$ is $a_n$ with $\alpha$ replaced by (an other irrational number) $\alpha/2$.
Since by the first fact a set $A=\{a'_n\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and $B$ is an image of the set
$A'$ by a continuous map onto $[-1,1]$, the set $B$ is dense in $[-1,1]$.